# Does YTM represent interest?

Tags: bond, yield

Does a bond's Yield to Maturity represent the amount of interest one gets at maturity even though it's expressed as a percentage? I read that it is a rate of return on a bond at maturity, but what is the "return"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_to_maturity

Answer (score 1):

Simply speaking, return means relative amount of *extra* money earned after investing of some amount of money: Return = $\frac{Received}{Invested}-1$.

If you invested \$100 and received \$100, this means you have zero return (\$100/\$100-1).

If you invested \$100 and received \$110, your return in 10% (\$110/\$100-1 = 1.1-1 = 0.1 = 10%).

Next step is account for term in which you received this return, and here comes a concept of yearly return. Formula is $1+r_y f = 1+r$ or $r_t = r/f$, where $r_y$ is year return, $f$ is fraction of a year, and $r$ is your previously calculated absolute return.

If you earned 10% in one year, it is your yearly return.

If you earned 10% in half year, then your yearly return is 10%/0.5 = 20%.

Next step is account for [Day count convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention) and [Compounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest) but it would be a long story.